It is not updating the state SetState Function
const [inventory, setInventory] = useState('')

    let web3

    useEffect(() =>{
        getInventoryHandler()
    },[inventory])

    const getInventoryHandler = async () => {
        try {
            // const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
            const inventory= await vmContract.methods.getVendingBalance().call()
            await setInventory(inventory)
            console.log(inventory)
            
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message)
        }
      } 

I am new to next.js and trying to get data from web 3 blockchain and my state is not updating i dont know why. But when i console.log 2 blank data are received before my actual resultenter image description here
Can you explain how it is working. Please help me

Hi, You don't need the await keyword before setInventory because your inventory state is a string. Since you're logging a block-scoped variable, i seems like await vmContract.methods.getVendingBalance().call() is returning an empty string, perhaps that's why you are seeing blank data

await vmContract.methods.getVendingBalance().call()

Your code uses the .call() method (docs) which sends a read-only call.
For state-changing operations, use the read-write .send() method (docs) instead.
Depending on your web3js configuration, the .send() method:

Signs the transaction directly from a configured account (your web3js instance needs to know its private key) and broadcasts it to the network

Sends a request to an external wallet (e.g. MetaMask) to sign the transaction (your web3js instance doesn't know the private key). Only after the user of the external wallet signs it, the transaction is then broadcasted to the network.


